# SQL : Stored procedure execution error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

In my stored procedure I am getting the following error

```
'price=ROUND(' CONVERT(VARCHAR, changeValue) + '/(1.00- marginPercent), 2) ' + sqlWhere
```

Error is:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

I have not found any syntax error. Please help  me on this. I'm using SQL Server 2000

Comment: Please paste ur written code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing `+` between `price=ROUND(` and `CONVERT(VARCHAR, changeValue)`

Comment: Yes.. I got it.  Thank you Alex

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax error in query,

correct the syntax error check below one & compare with your query

```
'price=ROUND('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, changeValue) + '/(1.00- marginPercent), 2) ' + sqlWhere
```

look into

```
ROUND('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, changeValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you given correct value at **VARCHAR**

'price=ROUND(' CONVERT(**VARCHAR**, changeValue)??

I think there is an error. You have not given the value.